# Conversion 'GridFSBucketWriteStream' to type 'WritableStream' impossible?

Tags: node.js, typescript, mongodb, mongoose

Recently the conversion of `GridFSBucketWriteStream` to type `WritableStream` became impossible and leads to a types error.

```
const wst = svcMng.DBService.projectImageGrid.openUploadStream(image.name);
const uploadPromise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const read = new Readable({
        read() {
            this.push(image.data);
            this.push(null);
        }
    });

    read.on('error', (err) => {
        reject(err);
    });
    read.on('end', () => {
        resolve(null);
    });
    read.pipe(wst);
});
await uploadPromise;
```

`read.pipe(wst)` leads to: Argument of type 'GridFSBucketWriteStream' is not assignable to parameter of type 'WritableStream'.

`wst` is a `GridFSBucketWriteStream` type and should be convertible to `WritableStream` as `GridFSBucketWriteStream` class implements `NodeJS.WritableStream`.

Of course `read.pipe(wst as any)` solve the issue but I would like to avoid it.

`read.pipe(wst as NodeJS.WritableStream)` is not working also.

Versions:

- mongoose: 6.1.4
- typescript: 4.1.2
- node v12.16.3

Thank you in advance for the help !

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*UPDATE: This issue has since been resolved (about 6 hours after my answer below) with mongodb version 4.3.0. (Here was the bug report: [jira.mongodb.org/browse/NODE-3843](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/NODE-3843))*

I ran into the same problem and found a workaround. It was implicitly installing @types/node version 17.0.8 (See @types/node/package.json in node_modules). The breaking change is between Node 16 and Node 17 in the `WritableStream` interface. The `end` method used to return `void` and now returns `this`.

You can specify the version of Node types you want by running:

`npm install --save-dev @types/node@16`

It seems in the long term, the mongodb Node driver project needs to fix its compatibility with Node 17. But this workaround helped me for now.