# Property 'end' in type 'GridFSBucketWriteStream' is not assignable to the same property in base type 'WritableStream'

Tags: node.js, mongodb, multer, multer-s3

```
node_modules/mongodb/mongodb.d.ts:3314:5 - error TS2416: Property 'end' in type 'GridFSBucketWriteStream' is not assignable to the same property in base type 'Writable'.
  Type '{ (): void; (chunk: Buffer): void; (callback: Callback<void | GridFSFile>): void; (chunk: Buffer, callback: Callback<void | GridFSFile>): void; (chunk: Buffer, encoding: BufferEncoding): void; (chunk: Buffer, encoding: BufferEncoding, callback: Callback<...>): void; }' is not assignable to type '{ (cb?: () => void): this; (chunk: any, cb?: () => void): this; (chunk: any, encoding: BufferEncoding, cb?: () => void): this; }'.

3314     end(chunk: Buffer, encoding: BufferEncoding | undefined, callback: Callback<GridFSFile | void>): void;
         ~~~
```

Earlier it was right, but when i added the feature to upload static files (images) to s3 bucket (using multer and multer-s3), I am getting this error on doing `yarn dev` to start the server which runs like this `"dev": "NODE_ENV=dev nodemon -e ts --exec \"npm run compile\"",`

My package.json scripts

```json
"scripts": {
    "compile": "tsc && node build/index.js | pino-pretty",
    "dev": "NODE_ENV=dev nodemon -e ts --exec \"npm run compile\"",
    "start": "NODE_ENV=prod node build/index.js | pino-pretty",
    "lint": "eslint . --ext .ts"
},
```

Update: It works somehow with the `start` script but not with the `dev` script. Also, it has taken the "dev" powers from me :(

Answer (score 2):

My problem was solved with this question:
[Conversion 'GridFSBucketWriteStream' to type 'WritableStream' impossible?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70589349/conversion-gridfsbucketwritestream-to-type-writablestream-impossible/70610562#70610562)

Solution: Downgrade the `@types/node` to `16` as `node 17` has breaking changes. Use
`npm i -D @types/node@16` or `yarn add -D @types/node@16` to do so

Answer (score 0):

Good news. This issue has since been resolved with mongodb version 4.3.0. (Here was the bug report: [jira.mongodb.org/browse/NODE-3843](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/NODE-3843))